# tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorrt

I am getting this warning from tensorflow with the following code:

```
import tensorrt
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I have looked at some of the posts about this but cannot determine if this is an issue for me. I have an NVIDIA Quadro GPU that I would like to use. What exactly does TensorRT do?

The output of my program no longer says that my GPU is not recognized.